# How do browsers UI elements available on the mobile phone platform?

Tags: user-interface, mobile, browser

I'm designing a website for the high end mobile phones, and I want to know how the different UI elements (e.g. buttons, check boxes, list boxes, textfields, etc) look like on different mobile browsers (eg safari, webkit, IE, etc) on different devices (e.g. Nokia, iPhone, etc). Can you offer some advice how I can get access to these without having to purchase the devices or using some online simulators?

Also I'm not so clear how these basic UI elements that is available from the platform works - do the mobile brwosers use their own UI elements or do they take the UI elements from the device OS and apply some visual style (e.g. checkboxes in safari looks different from that on IE on desktop browsers)?

Answer (score 1):

You can download emulators for most platforms. Here are a couple:

Blackberry: http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/resources/simulators.jsp

Windows: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C62D54A5-183A-4A1E-A7E2-CC500ED1F19A&displaylang=en

Nokia: http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/d57da811-c7cf-48c8-995f-feb3bea36d11/Nokia_Mobile_Internet_Toolkit_4.1.html

Just noticed that this was previously asked/answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464089/simulators-emulators-for-mobile-browser-testing